# Search text in richtextblock

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-store-apps, richtextblock

I want to search text in a richtextblock and get the textpointer or offset of the specifed text. How can I do? Which method can I use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for specified text in [Blocks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.richtextblock.blocks.aspx) property collection. Typically in blocks are [Paragraph](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.documents.paragraph.aspx) objects

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I write a method which can get all <Run> in my richtextblock. Thanks